# that would be amazing

Tags: meaning

> This evil demon thought experiment is Descartes’ way of pushing doubt
>   to its limits. If there was one thing that we could be sure the evil > demon couldn’t trick us about, **that would be amazing**. It would also > provide a way of answering those people who claim that we can’t know
>   anything at all for certain.

[A little history of philosophy, Nigel Warburton, Chapter XI]

What does the word "that" refer to? Is it the thing that we could be sure the evil demon couldn’t trick us about?

Answer (score 2):

I don’t think *that* is the (hypothetical) particular thing we could be sure the evil demon couldn’t trick us about- rather, *that* refers to the existence of such a thing. It’s really the whole clause that *that* is standing in for (“there was [being] one thing...”).